# Some letters missing in Godot RichTextLabel

Tags: fonts, rendering, godot

I have a dialog box in my 2D game implemented using a RichTextLabel with a custom font ([Vormgevers](https://arcade.itch.io/vormgevers) at 16px).

My game has an internal resolution of 432x243 (Project > Project Settings... > General > Display > Window > Size > Width / Height).

For some reason, sometimes letters in the dialog won't be displayed (the "i" in "in" is missing):

[image]

Even though they show correctly in the editor:

[image]

I also noticed that if I enter a space before the missing letter it shows up after the space:

[image]

I've tested the font and it works perfectly at this size on GIMP, so I'm guessing this issue has to do with the rendering the font in a small resolution...

Does anyone have any idea what I can I do to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Which stretch mode are you using (`2d` or `viewport`)? When using the `viewport` stretch mode, the viewport will keep its original resolution, which prevents pixels that are smaller than a viewport pixel to display. (This could cause letters to disappear due to precision errors.)

Comment: @Calinou I was using `viewport`, changing to `2d` made all letters show up but for some reason when I switch from windowed to fullscreen the space between the letters became considerably smaller. Check how the comma and the "y" pretty much merged: https://i.imgur.com/PxfwKZY.png Funnily enough this only happens to the text on RichTextLabel, the text to the right in a normal label shows up properly.